# Выполнение Cron команды с обратным временем

Tags: php, laravel, cron

Есть переменная, которая содержит время в часах. Нужно сделать команду `cron`, чтобы некоторая команда выполнялась за минуту до этого часа.

**Пример:** если в переменной 9 часов, то `cron-команда` должна выполниться в `8:59`. Сейчас это имеет такое решение. Есть ли более правильный способ чисто командой?

```
$hour = 10

if ($hour == 0) {
   $hour = 23;
} else {
   $hour = $hour - 1;
}

cron->("59 $hour * * *")
```

Comment: так передавай 8:59

Comment: @Jean-Claude. Как указано в условии, переменная выбранного часа регулируется(регулируется из админки)

Comment: Можно записать условие проверки чуть короче) ```$hour == 0 ? $hour = 23 : $hour--;```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
   $hour = 9;
   $date = new DateTime();
   $minusDate = $date->setTime($hour, 0, 0, 0)->sub(new DateInterval('PT1M'));
   echo $minusDate->format("i H * * *");
```

Comment: командой крон это никак не реализовать?

Comment: Строка для крона находится в последней строчке, используйте её вместо вывода в stdout.